# Is it possible to use Text or ByteString on HXT in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, text, web-scraping, bytestring, hxt

I think HXT, a XML/HTML processing library in Haskell, has really flexible and powerful methods for traversing and manipulating DOM trees by Arrows.
http://adit.io/posts/2012-04-14-working_with_HTML_in_haskell.html

It seems, however, HXT has only String representation for DOM node contents.
http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/hxt/9.1.6/doc/html/Text-XML-HXT-DOM-TypeDefs.html#t:XNode

Is it possible to use either of ByteString or Text for HXT? Text is preferred since I am using HXT with Yesod, which seems to mainly use Text.

Comment: I opened an [issue](https://github.com/UweSchmidt/hxt/issues/6) for this on github -

Answer (score 6):

Neither HXT nor HaXml appear to support either bytestring or text, but if you are working with Yesod you should probably use [xml-conduit](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/xml-conduit) and [html-conduit](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/html-conduit) anyway.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I tried xml-conduit and html-conduit, and they worked pretty nice with ByteString. I also made [dom-selector](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/dom-selector) package, which works on those two packages, to make it possible to traverse a DOM tree by css selectors.